# How to detect if we are in the Site Editor part of the Block Editor (as opposed to editing a Page/Post) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

We use JavaScript to unregister some Core blocks from the Page Editor. We'd like to unregister a slightly different list of blocks when using the Site Editor vs when editing a page or post.

Rather than something clunky to make this determination, such as looking at the current page's URL, does WordPress provide any native functions we can rely on? Some JavaScript version of get_current_screen or is_site_editor() or similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gutenberg and FSE: How to exclude a block from full site editing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/401518/gutenberg-and-fse-how-to-exclude-a-block-from-full-site-editing)

Comment: That is a super helpful answer and has a lot of important information and ideas to keep in mind. While it didn't directly answer my question, inspecting the page source to look for things mentioned there DID get me exactly what I was looking for. I will post that as an Answer now. thank you!

Comment: yes, good points made by Tom there regarding possible conflicts removing blocks only from a single context. Otherwise it's also possible to target the `wp-edit-site` handle with `wp_add_inline_script()` to add inline script like `wp.domReady( function(){ wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType( 'core/html' );});` or use `admin_enqueue_scripts` for larger scripts. There is also a way to use the PHP filter `allowed_block_types_all` and target the block editor's context there with `$block_editor_context->name === 'core/edit-site'` ... etc but we just keep the above in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Block Editor, in both the context of the editing pages or the Site Editor, actually does provide some simple variables in JavaScript similar to the data that is available via get_current_screen in PHP.

Sample variables in Page Editor:

```
var ajaxurl = '/mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
pagenow = 'page',
typenow = 'page',
adminpage = 'post-new-php',
thousandsSeparator = ',',
decimalPoint = '.',
isRtl = 0;
```

Sample variables in Site Editor:

```
var ajaxurl = '/mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
pagenow = 'site-editor',
typenow = '',
adminpage = 'site-editor-php',
thousandsSeparator = ',',
decimalPoint = '.',
isRtl = 0;
```

So one can simply access 'pagenow' to make the determination which context we are in.